# How do I use Localxpose to SSH into a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, raspberry-pi, tunnel

I want to SSH into my Raspberry Pi 4 when I'm away from home. I already have a Localxpose account, so I figured I would use that. I know I have my keys configured properly, since I can successfully SSH into the pi on my home network. My pi is running Ubuntu 23.10 and is running a service

```
[Unit]
Description=localxpose
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/octa/loclx tunnel tcp --reserved-endpoint us.loclx.io:4545 --to localhost:22
Restart=always
RestartSec=15

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

From my local machine (Windows 10) I can run `ssh us.loclx.io:4545\\octa@raspberrypi` at which point I am prompted for my user's password, but permission is denied every time. Is it possible to make this work or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Is it your account free or paid?

Comment: @RomeoNinov it is paid. I should also add that I am logged into my account from the pi with my token added.